# PFTableViewCell not changing labelText

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift, ios8

The below code is supposed to take the name field from the PFObject being passed into cellForRowAtIndexPath and set the textLabel.text field to the name (ie the tableView row could potentially read "sneeze1"). I'm able to change the height of each row with the heightForRowAtIndexPath method and also see the correct number of calls to cellForRowAtIndexPath (3 rows loaded into a class on Parse's Data Browser in my specific case) with the right fields, but I can't get the textLabel.text to change.

Is there some other step that needs to be completed before a textLabel can have its text changed?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell! {
    var cellIdentifier = "EventCell"

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? PFTableViewCell

    if !cell {
        cell = PFTableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }

    var name = object["name"] as? String
    cell!.textLabel.text = name
    println("textLabel: \(cell!.textLabel.text)" + "  name: \(name)")

    return cell
}
```

Comment: may be you are not reloading the tableview.

Comment: What text do you actually see in the cell? ie. does it work the first time and then can't be changed or is it just blank?

Comment: No, the only text I see is the default text specified in the Storyboard I'm using, which I set to "Default Text". It just doesn't change when I set it, and, oddly, it shows the correct number of rows (3 in my test case) and also allows me to change the height of the rows. I just can't set the textLabel.text or subtitle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the text to change when I set used the UITableViewCell cellForRowAtIndexPath. It looks like the problem is with Parse's PFTableViewCell potentially mixing with Swift. It's not allowing me to change the text on PFTableViewCell.

As a side note, the code works even when the below method exists in my PFQueryTableViewController side-by-side with the above PFTableViewCell cellForRowAtIndexPath. Somehow, the code is actually just running the UITableViewCell cellForRowAtIndexPath method instead.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cellIdentifier = "EventCell"

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell

    if !cell {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }

    var name = "HELLO"//object["name"] as? String
    cell!.textLabel.text = name
    println("textLabel: \(cell!.textLabel.text)" + "  name: \(name)")
    //cell.imageView.file = object.objectForKey(self.imageKey) as PFFile

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use the original delegate signature, else your method won't get called. Instead of

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell!
```

use

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
```

Comment: I'm using Parse.com's PFTableViewController, so the method signature is actually correct in this case. The cellForRowAtIndexPath method is actually getting called in my code. I can potentially try to not use Parse.com's functions to see what happens though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `as?` returns an optional type, so `name` is of type `String?`.

Try this instead if you really want to handle missing names:

```
if let name = object["name"] as? String {
    cell!.textLabel.text = name
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point, and I will change the code to handle null object["name"] values, but in this specific case, it won't help. All of the object["name"] values are actually set when they reach that part of the code. The println statement has values each time its called.